# How to update ng-class based on ng-change?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-ngmodel, ng-class

I have an ng-repeat that creates several widgets, each with it's own select dropdown.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in widget.items" class="col-md-6">
    <select ng-model="item.chosenTag"
            ng-change="widget.updateTag(item)"
            ng-class="widget.getButtonClass(item.tag, item.id)">

        <option value="companies"
                ng-selected="{{item.tag == 'companies'}}"
                changed="companies">companies</option>

        <option value="news"
                ng-selected="{{item.tag == 'news'}}"
                changed="news">news</option>

        <option value="people"
                ng-selected="{{item.tag == 'people'}}"
                changed="people">people</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

As the view is loaded, the `ng-class="widget.getButtonClass(item.tag, item.id)"` calls a function to check if 2 values are met, then sets `ng-class` to either `btn-success` or `btn-default`.

```
// This checks the view after load to change the class on each widget select
var vm = this;
vm.getButtonClass = function(tag, id) {

    console.log('in getButtonClass');

    if (tag && id) {
        return 'btn-success';
    } else {
        return 'btn-default';
    }
};
```

---

Next if the user now updates a select within any widget, `ng-change` will update to the correct value.

**However I need to somehow re-run** the `ng-class` check or rather just go ahead and add `btn-success` to the select without having to refresh the page.

How would you go about accomplishing this?

Is there a way to do something like this?

`ng-class="{ functionToUpdateAll | boolean based on ng-change }"`

Comment: Do you have any plnkr/fiddle for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any specific reason that you need to call the function? Why dont you bind directly to those variables?

```
ng-class="'btn-success':item.tag && item.id, 'btn-default': !(item.tag && item.id)"
```

In that way you take advantage of mutual binding i.e. whenever the item.tag or item.id are changed, the class will be evaluated accordingly.

Comment: I had originally done this, but was told to keep logic out of the view, but now due to my new issue, may have to revert back to doing it that way...

Comment: This is not a logic yet a UI specific code. i.e. You are deciding on the class of HTML element. Cant get more UI related than this.

Comment: Ok this is working the same as the function before, however it does not update ng-class on the fly, if I make a change to the `select / ng-change` is there a way to combine both? Or even just fake add `btn-success` on any change? If the user refreshes they will get the correct data to set all select classes.

Comment: hmm... this has to work unless there a problem in your code... do you have a plunker? BTW You can always watch the 'item.tag + item.id' and update a new variable called (such as item.cssClass) and use that as your class. Again I wouldnt do this unless it is necessary.

Comment: Ah it does not work because the id is the user id that is set AFTER the change hits the DB so I have to use this hack for now: `item.id = 1;` inside of my `updateTag` function. However your code with the `ui-logic` on the page allows me to be able to update the code on the fly, as well as on page load :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that instead of calling the function in `ng-class`, just assign it to a variable:

```
<select ng-model="item.chosenTag"
            ng-change="widget.updateTag(item)"
            ng-class="mySelectClass">
```

And in your `updateTag` function in the controller update that variable:

```
vm.updateTag = function(item) {

    if (item.tag && item.id) {
        vm.mySelectClass = 'btn-success';
    } else {
        vm.mySelectClass = 'btn-default';
    }
};
```

Comment: This is good, however 2 problems. When the page loads I can't call the current ng-class function to set all select classes based on previous data. 2nd, changing this adds `btn-success` to every select in every widget.

Comment: @LeonGaban Oh, wasn't aware you had several widgets, my bad. Regarding your first issue - can't you run a function on the controller init to set initial values? 2nd issue - I would create different variables for different widgets. You can have `ng-class="mySelectClass{{$index}}"`. You can also have `ng-init="setInitialValue()"` and set up initial values for each widget. This actually fixes issue # 1 as well.